# Where is JIT code cache&generated code saved in Android N?

Tags: android, jit, aot

I have read https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-the-road-to-jitaot-hybrid-compilation-based-application-user-experience?language=ru. The article is very helpful to understand android AOT&JIT, especially about hot&cold/warm code.

But I have questions about these sentences.

------------1----------------

### *Once the total of the counts exceeds yet another higher threshold, the warm method becomes hot and is compiled by the JIT compiler into native executable code, which is stored in the JIT code cache along with the collected profile information.*

Here I want to know where is the JIT code cache? Is it under /data/dalvik-cache folder?And where is the collected profile information?

-----------2---------------

### *One major development seen in the AOSP master based JIT compiler is that ART will record which methods are hot and save their names for later AOT recompilation. When the device is unused (and charging) for over long duration, a service will compile the hot methods and save the generated code.*

Here where is the generated code saved? Is is the same .dex file under /data/dalvik-cache?

If anyone know more about android AOT&JIT, wish you can help.

Thanks.